# Rendering artifact when using Eclipse (FlashBuilder)

Tags: windows-7, eclipse, rendering, nvidia-quadro

Once in a while when using FlashBuilder, I'll get a rendering artifact that doesn't go away until I do a full reboot. This artifact seems to be caused by a popup triggered by code documentation popups (hovering over keywords) that linger after the popup has been dismissed:

[image]

This behavior is seemingly random and incredibly annoying. It only happens when using Eclipse (although I don't run many Java-based programs) and run an NVidia Quadro 2000M (with the latest drivers - figured I'd try that before posting).

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any known solutions?

Comment: Hitting windows key + d twice should get rid of any screen artifacts.

Comment: @Brian: No sir, unfortunately didn't do the trick.